# Mysql service refuse to be started

Tags: linux, mysql

Mysql service just stop working. once I typed: `service mysql start`The linux system displayed the following:

```
tail: invalid option -- n
Try `tail --help' for more information.
tail: invalid option -- n
Try `tail --help' for more information.
/etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with is too full! failed!
```

Knowing that I didnt edit the mysql file, it is always like that and my server ist not full because I checked this with df command.
What can I do about it?

The     `-type f -name tail` gives:

```
/bin/tail
/home/vhosts/Site1/bin/tail
/home/vhosts/Site2/bin/tail
/home/vhosts/Site3/bin/tail
/home/vhosts/Site4/bin/tail
/home/vhosts/Site5/bin/tail
/home/vhosts/chroot/bin/tail
/var/www/vhosts/chroot/bin/tail
/var/www/shops/Site6/bin/tail
/usr/bin/tail
```

Comment: The weirdness begins with the `invalid option` error from `tail` since `-n` is very much a correct option. What happens if you call e.g. `tail -n 2 /etc/fstab` in the terminal?

Comment: No it works fine in fact

Comment: Even if the disk is not full, it might be having too many files or folders. can you show your `df -h` and `df -i`

Comment: should I upgrade mysql version? I have no idea what to do

Comment: one directory is 10% the other is 17% Im sure this not the problem.

Comment: What OS are you on? What happens it you edit `/etc/init.d/mysql` to contain the line `which tail` and then call `service mysql status`? Is it the same output as when you issue this command on the shell (e.g. both `/usr/bin/tail`)?

Comment: I edited in fact but it didt help since once I commeted this line mysql (status,stop,start,restart)is not responding any more

Comment: Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.10 (lenny)
Release: 5.0.10
Codename: lenny

Comment: What likely happens there is that the call to `tail` fails for some reason and therefore, the script doesn't get the path for the mysql data dir and fails to start the daemon, with a misleading error message. What happens if you run `find / -type f -name tail` (will take a long time!) Do you get more than one line of output? If yes, it might be that your system is compromised, which isn't so unlikely considering that Debian Lenny is EOL for two years now.

Comment: find / -type f -name tail didnt took too much in fact to be excetude. What can I do to fix this

Comment: and yes I get many lines as an output

Comment: Can you add this output to your question, or a part of it?

Comment: @SvW I have already edit the question could you please take a look

Comment: try running `mysqld` or `mysqld_safe` directly to bypass init scripts

Comment: @LinuxDevOps thx it works you could post your comment as an answer so I kan mark it as resolved :)

Comment: sure, glad I could help. Ideally you want to look at what the problem in the init script was/is.

Comment: @SvW your right my system was attacked in last two weeks and it was  compromised but I have already (thought) saved the problem.What do you recommend in oder to fix this I mean to protect the system. Have I to install the debian new version ?

Comment: there is good advice at http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server but in a nutshell yes, if your system was compromised at that level you want a clean install and then move your data.

Comment: Thx I have already took a look at this post since 2 weeks. I just want to add a comment according to the question, `service mysql status` shows that the service is running BUT always the same annoying mysterious error tail: `tail: invalid option -- n
Try tail --help for more information.
/usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.41 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (C) 2000-2006 MySQL AB
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL license`

Comment: in a compromised server you can't trust anything, binaries (like tail) or init scripts are cahnged and don't work properly and hence the weird messages

Comment: have I to upgrade the system to Wheezy 7? If yes, have I to update the php version `php -v` `PHP 5.2.6`... I know that the version have to be updated too but right now I have to not update it so the question is **would this php version work with the Debian Wheezy?**

Comment: you don't have to upgrade to the latest distro version although if possible it would be a good idea. check the php version in Wheezy/whatever and the changes in php to see if they are compatible with your code, situation too broad to have a short answer, better to just try in a new server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem in the initialization scripts, temporarily you can try running `mysqld` or `mysqld_safe` to bypass them.

Comment: Check your my.cnf to see what start options you have defined. Sounds like you've got a hosed init script.

Comment: By the way despite that the solution worked but the service sttoped once again by it self and it refuses to be started :(

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins it mysql start displays ERROR 2002 C'ant connect to local Mysql server through soket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2).. and in deed this file is not existing under this path

Comment: with find command I figure out there is no such a file mysqld.sock or mysql.sock in all the server directories..How can I fix that?